# Can someone help me with understanding what this statement is actually saying?

Tags: logic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, quantifiers

$$\forall x\in \mathbb R\,\exists y\in \mathbb R\text{ such that }x+y>0\implies xy>0$$

Can someone explain to me Why this statement is True and how the Quantifiers effect it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Such that" is unusual in math in this form, and it is hard to figure out what is meant by it here.

Comment: For every real number $x$, you can find a real number $y$ such that the implication "$x+y>0$ implies $xy>0$" is true.  Yes, this is in fact a true statement... whatever the choice is of $x$ we can choose $y$ to be $y=-x-1$.  This makes it so that the hypothesis in the implication is false which makes the implication vacuously true.

Comment: Particular, does it mean "such that $(x+y>0\implies xy>0)?$" Or does it mean "such that $x+y>0$ and $xy>0$." The first is more natural, but it is trivially true, because you can take $y=-x-1$ and get that $x+y>0$ is false, and thus $x+y>0\implies xy>0.$ So there exists a $y$ for which it is true. But the other reading ignores the $\implies$ symbol. The other reading is false, but I think the first reading is what you want.

Comment: The key is that it is bad form to mix symbolic language and English like this. There are formal ways to write either reading, but once you break out of the formal language, readers are left guessing which you mean.

Comment: Is this even true for negative $x$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see no other interpretation other than the one I wrote above for the statement that is syntactically valid and will read aloud whatever whitespace, colon, or bar that follows an existential quantifier as "such that."  I see no problem with having used full english words here rather than shorthand, symbols, or omission as they all have the same meaning.  In particular, for this example since $y$ appears both before and after the implication, we know that $\exists y$ must be a part of what leads to the implication, and not a part of the hypothesis of the implication.

Comment: @LanierFreeman By taking $y=-x-1$ regardless of whether $x$ was positive or negative you have $x+y = x+(-x-1) = (x-x)-1 = -1$ is not greater than zero.  Yes, it works for negative $x$ as well.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews with regards to your "other reading" which replaced the implication "$\implies$" with an "and"... of course that is a different statement.  Implications and conjunctions are not equivalent.  Nobody should have correctly interpreted that as having a conjunction there... I don't know why you have implied that anyone would.

Comment: @JMoravitz I feel like I'm missing something. Let $x=-10$. For $x+y>0$ to be true, $y>10$. But then $xy<0$, making it false.

Comment: @LanierFreeman Apparently I stand corrected with my comment earlier to ThomasAndrews as here you are, incorrectly interpreting that as a conjunction.  That is wrong to do.  We do not require here that $x+y>0$ be true.  We merely require the *implication* "$x+y>0\implies xy>0$" be true.  The implication can be true when we have both hypothesis and conclusion both be true, yes.  The implication can also be *vacuously true* when the hypothesis is false and the conclusion is either.  By taking $y=-x-1=9$ we have $x+y>0$ is *not* true and therefore the implication is vacuously true as a result.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the response

Comment: @JMoravitz Right, but once formal notation is broken, you have to guess what the writer is intending, not what the symbols tell you. The writer is clearly mixing up notations, so you can only guess what the writer means. Here, the first reading seems dubious in meaning, having so many vacuous cases, so one might try to guess what the writer actually intended. If the writer intended "such that" to only apply to the $x+y>0,$ then implication wouldn't make sense. I agree the first reading is how I'd read it, too, however.

Comment: There is no need to guess though... and in no reasonable interpretation should we feel justified in swapping implication symbols with conjunction symbols... That would be like "$2$ plus $3\times 4$" suddenly being interpreted as $2+3\div 4$, replacing $\times$ with $\div$ at a whim just because we used the word 'plus' rather than the symbol earlier...  $\times$ and $\div$ can not be swapped arbitrarily in a statement any more than $\implies$ and $\wedge$ can

Answer (score 1):

With **quantified statements** you can think of it as a game:

Someone gives you an $x \in \mathbb R$, then you have to find an $y \in \mathbb R$ such that the implication $$x+y>0 \implies xy>0$$ is true.

Now you can see, that this statement is **always true**. Because for every $x \in \mathbb R$ you're given, you can find an $y \in \mathbb R$ such that the implication is always true. Just define your $y \in \mathbb R$ as $$y=-x$$ and the expression $x+y>0$ will always be false, which makes the implication always true. (Anything can be deduced from something that is false.)

Hope that helps!